# Multiple NavigationLink in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Can you have multiple `NavigationLink`s in SwiftUI? The following only displays the first Link:

```
struct Test : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("First")) {
                Text("Visible")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Second")) {
                Text("Invisible")
            }
            //EDIT: Also Invisible
            Text("Not rendered")
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Turns out everything under the first `NavigationLink` is not displayed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put your views inside a VStack:

```swift
struct Test : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("First")) {
                    Text("Visible")
                }

                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Second")) {
                    Text("Invisible")
                }
                //EDIT: Also Invisible
                Text("Not rendered")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its in VStack only although its not working.

Comment: How would I connect the Navigations to a button? Example: Button is pressed and it activates one of the navigation links.

Answer (score 2):

Look you can definitely have multiple NavigationLinks but here you are doing one things wrong.

The body property returns a single View but here you are trying to return more than one views, which causes the error.

To Solve this issue we put them inside another View like a VStack or a HStack, like shown above in the answer given by kontiki.

Answer (score 1):

see apple example, that has a clean impelementation.
Here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink

If You need to

1. add navigation on buttons, You have simply to set a state var un button action, (button will be where You put Text("xxvisible") ), say it ***selection***.
2. in Apple code:

   ...

   detail: {
   if let color = selection {
   ColorDetail(color: color)
   } else {
   Text("Pick a color")
   }
   }

replace color with Your ***selection*** and use else or switch/case.